# Is $\mbox{Ext}^1_{\mathfrak g}(V(\lambda), M)$ one-dimensional?

Tags: solution-verification, representation-theory, lie-algebras, exact-sequence

Let $\lambda \in P^+$ and consider the Verma module $M(\lambda)$ with irreducible quotient $V(\lambda)$. So, there exists a maximal submodule $M\subseteq M(\lambda)$ such that $M(\lambda)/M \cong V(\lambda),$ whence we derive the exact sequence

$$0 \rightarrow M \rightarrow M(\lambda) \rightarrow V(\lambda)\rightarrow 0.$$

The above exact sequence does not split, since $M(\lambda)$ is indecomposable. Suppose even further that $M$ is a simple $\mathfrak g$-module. **In this case, is $\mbox{Ext}_\mathfrak g (V(\lambda),M)$ 1-dimensional?** That is, any non-splitting exact sequence $0\rightarrow M \rightarrow W \xrightarrow{\,\pi\,} V(\lambda) \rightarrow 0$ implies that $W\cong M(\lambda)$?

My efforts so far were the following: Let $u\in W$ be such that $\pi(u)$ is a highest weight vector of weight $\lambda$, so that $W' = U(\mathfrak g)u \subseteq W$ is a highest weight module of weight $\lambda$, and such that $V(\lambda)$ is isomorphic to a quotient of $W'$ by restriction of $\pi$ to $W'$. Since $M$ and $V(\lambda)$ are irreducible, from the exact sequence $0\rightarrow M \rightarrow W \rightarrow V(\lambda)$ we have that $W$ is a module of length $2$, with $W'$ being  a module of lenght $\leq 2$ by consequence. If $W'$ is of length $1$, it is simple, whence it follows that $W'\cong V(\lambda)$, as $V(\lambda)$ is a quotient of $W'$. If $W'$ is of length $2$, then $W' = W$. The former case would imply that $0\rightarrow M \rightarrow W \xrightarrow{\,\pi\,} V(\lambda) \rightarrow 0 $ splits, so we must have $W= W'$. Therefore, $W'$ is a highest weight module of weight $\lambda$ and is, thus, isomorphic to a quotient of $M(\lambda)$. From the exact sequences $0\rightarrow M \rightarrow M(\lambda) \rightarrow V(\lambda)\rightarrow 0$ and $0 \rightarrow M \rightarrow W \rightarrow V(\lambda) \rightarrow 0$, we conclude that $W' = W$ and $M(\lambda)$ have the same dimension, so that $W'= W\cong M(\lambda)$.

**Edit:** The Verma Module is not finite dimensional. So I cannot state that $M(\lambda)$ and $W'=W$ have the same dimesion by the argument above...

Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: It doesn't split because the Verma is indecomposable (it has a unique simple quotient!)

Comment: @MatthewTowers Thank you, I remembered the proof of that now. The question has been edited

Comment: What is the reasoning for length of $W'$ to be $\leq 2$? and how the the statement following this assertion is justified? There seems to be some typo regarding the map $W \rightarrow M(\lambda)$. Some more details with references will be helpful for non-experts as well. Thanks!

Comment: @random123 $W$ itself has length 2, because of the exact sequence $0\rightarrow M \rightarrow W \rightarrow V(\lambda) \rightarrow 0$. Since $V(\lambda)$ is isomorphic to a quotient of $W'$, if $W'$ is of length 1, then $W'$ is simple and we have $W' \cong V(\lambda)$. If $W'$ is of lenght 2, then it equals $W$ itself. The former can not happen, because the sequence does not split. So $W= W'$.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you again. Why would $W$ or for that matter $M(\lambda)$ itself will have length 2? What I have in mind is the proposition 7.6.8 in Dixmier's Enveloping algebras. I might be confusing myself but some clarification will be helpful. Thank you. Also, may I suggest that you add further details in the argument you outlined in the question above.

Comment: @random123 You are correct. $M(\lambda)$ is not necessairly of lenght 2, because $M$ can be anything. Maybe what I am trying to prove is valid only for $M$ simple. I will edit the question with better arguments